# How to use black translucent status bar upon startup - info.plist key/value doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, coding-style, sdk, statusbar

I have no problem setting the status bar of my app in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` messsage.

However, the problem is, when my app is launched, the splash screen (default.png) is displayed with the standard colored status bar (some type of silver color).  Then, once my app loads, it is changed to black translucent.

So... after doing a bit of research, I was told to add the following key/value to my info.plist file:
`UIStatusBarStyle` as the key
`UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` as the value

I've done that, rebuilt, etc.  However, I don't see anything different.  I still get the default status bar when the splash screen is displayed.  Same result with simulator as well as device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try going to Build/Clean all targets, deleting the "/build/" directory, and then building the app again.

Comment: Yep - I've done all that, still same behavior

Comment: have you tried the viewWillAppear method?

Comment: viewWillAppear?  I change the status bar to black translucent long before then, I do it the first line of code in the app delegate (didFinishLaunching).  It works fine.  Thats not the issue here.  We're talking about how to get it to display during the splash screen load.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can. The `info.plist` is loaded "before" the app launches, thus you can add a **Status bar style** key to it and set the value to your desired style. Now you will have the status bar changed right from the splash screen.

Comment: Worked! This is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I face the same problem with you, repeating the info.plist steps and it didn't work. This is what I do:

1. Uninstall the app in your simulator/device.
2. Clean the project and close the Xcode application.
3. **Go to your project folder -> build folder, clean everything in the Build folder, 'FileMaps', 'Headers', 'Intermediates', 'PrecompiledHeaders', 'Products' etc.**.
4. Restart your project and go to the infoPlist list AGAIN to see whether the status bar type list disappear. If it is, set it again.
5. Build your project.

I know this is quite an old post but I just want to updated it for others who face this problem in future.